# numpy array slow with large list

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, yolov8, luxonis

I am using an OAK-D from luxonis and trying to implement myself YOLOv8 segmentation in the camera.

I am having problems with latency because for each frame I use rigth now about 0.14s, the problem is that the np.array is a huge bottleneck.

Using yolov8n-seg I get the next results:

For output0 of YOLOv8-seg with dimensions -> (1, 116, 8400) and total len list = 974400 I need **0.05s**

For output1 of YOLOv8-seg with dimensions -> (1, 32, 160, 160) and total len list = 819200 I need **0.03s**

In total 0.08s of a total 0.14s (about 57% of each frame only to do this).

My question is if there is some way of transform a list of lenght of a million to a numpy array in a fast way.

Or which is the best way to transform a flat list into a (1, 116, 8400) or (1, 32, 160, 160) numpy array.

I have tried np.reshape, np.fromiter and transforming first the list with np.array but I get more or less the same result.

UPDATE: I update with my code here:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import depthai as dai
import time
from YOLOSeg import YOLOSeg

pathYoloBlob = "./yolov8n-seg.blob"

# Create OAK-D pipeline
pipeline = dai.Pipeline()

cam_rgb = pipeline.createColorCamera()
cam_rgb.setPreviewSize(640, 640)  
cam_rgb.setInterleaved(False)

nn = pipeline.create(dai.node.NeuralNetwork)
nn.setBlobPath(pathYoloBlob)

cam_rgb.preview.link(nn.input)

xout_rgb = pipeline.createXLinkOut()
xout_rgb.setStreamName("rgb")
cam_rgb.preview.link(xout_rgb.input)

xout_nn_yolo = pipeline.createXLinkOut()
xout_nn_yolo.setStreamName("nn_yolo")
nn.out.link(xout_nn_yolo.input)

# Start aplication
with depthai.Device(pipeline) as device:

    q_rgb = device.getOutputQueue("rgb")
    q_nn_yolo = device.getOutputQueue("nn_yolo")


    frame = None

    # Since the detections returned by nn have values from <0..1> range, they need to be multiplied by frame width/height to
    # receive the actual position of the bounding box on the image
    def frameNorm(frame, bbox):
        normVals = np.full(len(bbox), frame.shape[0])
        normVals[::2] = frame.shape[1]
        return (np.clip(np.array(bbox), 0, 1) * normVals).astype(int)

    # Main host-side application loop
    while True:

        in_rgb = q_rgb.tryGet()
        in_nn_yolo = q_nn_yolo.tryGet()

        if in_rgb is not None:

            frame = in_rgb.getCvFrame()  

            if in_nn_yolo is not None:
                
                # Here is the problem
                output0 = np.reshape(in_nn_yolo.getLayerFp16("output0"), newshape=([1, 116, 8400]))
                output1 = np.reshape(in_nn_yolo.getLayerFp16("output1"), newshape=([1, 32, 160, 160]))               
 
                # Si tenemos ambos outputs podemos calcular la mascara final
                if( len(output0) > 0 and len(output1) > 0 ):                 

                    #Post-process, this is fast, no problems here
                    yoloseg = YOLOSeg("", conf_thres=0.3, iou_thres=0.5)
                    yoloseg.prepare_input_for_oakd(frame.shape[:2])
                    yoloseg.segment_objects_from_oakd(output0,output1)
                    combined_img = yoloseg.draw_masks(frame.copy())
                    cv2.imshow("Output", combined_img)

            else:
                print("in_nn_yolo EMPTY")

        else:
            print("in_rgb EMPTY")
        # at any time, you can press "q" and exit the main loop, therefore exiting the program itself
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break
```

Comment: Why do you have this list in the first place? Why not work with NumPy arrays from the beginning? A [mcve] would help

Comment: I am using an OAK-D and the function getLayerFp16("output0") to get the data, as far as I know I can not retrieve the data in numpy format. https://docs.luxonis.com/projects/api/en/latest/references/python/?highlight=getLayerFp16#depthai.NNData.getLayerFp16

Comment: @ForceBru I update the question with my code.

Comment: Looking at the docs, it seems like it's just a weird API that hands out lists when it should really be returning NumPy arrays or Torch tensors. Perhaps there are other functions/methods that return those?

Comment: In time tests on a 1e6 element list, `np.fromiter` takes about the same time as a list comprehension.  `np.array` takes twice as long, presumably because it iterates on the list twice, once to determine the dtype and shape, and again to fill the values into an array.  Added `reshape` time is negligible.

Comment: Have you tried fixing the data type? E.g. `output0 = np.array(in_nn_yolo.getLayerFp16("output0"), dtype=np.float16).reshape([1, 116, 8400])`

Comment: @arne It's an array of regular floats, the `fp16` just refers to how to interpret the source data. The underlying C++ function returns `std::vector<float>`, and automatic pybind11 conversion makes it into a Python list of Python floats.

Comment: Looking at the source code, that is indeed silly implementation of the wrappers, since the C++ API makes a nice flat vector of floats. However, they do use pybind11, and conveniently included its numpy header as well (but only used the functionality for a single function). Patching the bindings to go directly to a numpy array would be fairly simple.

Comment: @DanMašek Could you give me some advice to do that? I guess I have to change "depthai-python-main\src\pipeline\datatype\NNDataBindings.cpp" in123


```C++
.def("getLayerFp16", &NNData::getLayerFp16, py::arg("name"), DOC(dai, NNData, getLayerFp16))
```
or "depthai-core-main\src\pipeline\datatype\NNData.cpp" function in 221

```C++

std::vector<float> NNData::getLayerFp16(const std::string& name) const {
```

I only have code in python hence I am a bit lost working with C++ or pybind11. And I guess I will have to compile the library after I made the changes...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I'd only modify the things in `NNDataBindings.cpp`, you found the right spot. I'd leave the existing binding for `getLayerFp16` as it is, and create a new one with a distinct name for the new return type. That seems to be least invasive modification. | Yes, you will need to rebuild that library once you apply the changes. But once you get something working you can probably make a pull request, or at least create an issue with feature request and a nice example on their Github repo. | I'll write up some example code for you over the weekend when I have some time.